# trying to saving my stream in my viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble saving the stream of my selected picture from my galary.
this is what i'm trying.

```
Stream stream = _stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync();

if (stream != null)
{
    ItemPic = (StreamImageSource)ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
}
```

_stream is also a Stream and the image shows up in my application but my _stream field is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to cache the stream using the _stream field for some future use. Since the .net **Stream** class implements the **IDisposable** interface it relies on you to release this unmanaged resource manually (in contrast to the garbage collector doing it for you).

I would rather cache the underlying stream data and dispose the stream instead of trying to hold on to it.

```
using(Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync())
{
   if (stream != null)
   {
      // save stream data as an byte array 
      _streamData = ReadBytes(stream);
      ItemPic = GetImageSource(_streamData);
   }
}

// a helper method to get the stream data
private byte[] ReadBytes(Stream input)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

// a helper method to create an image from an byte array
private ImageSource GetImageSource(byte[] data)
{
   return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(data)
}
```

Comment: i tried this but now my picture is not showing on my screen. whenever i do something extra with the stream my picture is not showing up anymore.